# AttributeError: <class> instance has no attribute <>

Tags: python, pyserial

I am new to python so need your help on the following error message. I have two files first one is "test1.py" which is I am running and has the following code.

```
import sys, time, re, os, pickle

from ComLib import *

obj = Com()
obj.ComOpen()
obj.ComReset()
obj.ComClose()
```

and the second file is "ComLib.py" and has the following code

```
import serial, sys, re, pickle, time


class Com:
    def ComOpen(self):
        self = serial.Serial()
        self.port = "COM1"
        self.baudrate = 9600
        self.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS     #number of bits per bytes
        self.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE     #set parity check: no parity
        self.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE  #number of stop bits
        self.timeout = 1                     #non-block read
        self.xonxoff = True                  #disable software flow control
        self.rtscts = False                  #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
        self.dsrdtr = False                  #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
        self.writeTimeout = 2                #timeout for write

        self.open()
        return


    def ComClose(self):
        self.close()
        return

    def ComReset(self):
       print "Executing ComReset function...!!"

       self.write("~~~~~~~~~~\r")

       i = 0
       while i<10 :
          response = self.readline()
          print "Inside first while loop...!!"
          print "response = "+response

          if (response == ':'):
             print "-->colon found...ready for next input<---"
             break

          i=i+1
          time.sleep(0.5)

       return
```

While executing the above I am getting the following error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vgupta\Desktop\KeyAT\final\WDEAutomationTestSuite\WDETestSuite\Bootguard\TC#001.py", line 17, in <modul
e>
    obj.ComReset()
  File "C:\Users\vgupta\Desktop\KeyAT\final\WDEAutomationTestSuite\APILib\ComLib.py", line 52, in ComReset
    self.write("~~~~~~~~~~\r")
AttributeError: Com instance has no attribute 'write'"
```

Can anyone help me out in finding out what is wrong here.

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: self = serial.Serial() smells.. Maybe you wanted hineritance? http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: Agreed. If that worked the way you seem to think it does, your instance would be replaced with a `Serial` instance and would no longer have any of the methods. It does not work that way; you're merely reassigning the local variable `self` to a new `Serial` instance, then setting some attributes on it and calling its `open()`... and then throwing it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your decleration Should be:

> ```
> self.sSerial = serial.Serial() 
> self.sSerial.port = "COM1"
> self.sSerial.baudrate = 9600
> .........
> ```

then you can do `self.sSerial.write("~~~~~~~~~~\r")`

1. class Com is missing `__init__`

Comment: `self.sSerial = serial.Serial('COM1', baudrate=9600)` sounds a lot more intuitive...